# No Overload for method which takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update gridview. Here, I have used 3 tier architecture method.

Here is my GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ResllerID"
          ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRecord" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reseller Name" SortExpression="ResellerName">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ResellerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ResellerName") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ResellerName") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile Number" SortExpression="MobileNumber">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MobileTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MobileNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>  
                 </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference Number" SortExpression="ReferenceNumber">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ReferenceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReferenceNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReferenceNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code: I am getting error ResellerBL.UpdateReseller(resellerId, name.Text, mobileNumber.Text, referenceNumber.Text); It says No Overload for method which takes 4 arguments

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = ResellerBL.GetResellers();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int resellerId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
        TextBox mobileNumber = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0];
        TextBox referenceNumber = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0];

        ResellerBL.UpdateReseller(resellerId, name.Text, mobileNumber.Text, referenceNumber.Text);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = ResellerBL.GetResellers();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

ResellerBL code:

```
public static void UpdateReseller(Reseller reseller)
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [Resellers] SET [ResellerName] = @ResellerName, [ReferenceNumber] = @ReferenceNumber WHERE [ResellerID] = @ResellerID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResellerName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = reseller.ResellerName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", SqlDbType.Text).Value = reseller.MobileNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNumber", SqlDbType.Text).Value = reseller.ReferenceNumber;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResllerID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = reseller.ResllerID;

        DbUtility.UpdateDb(cmd);
    }
```

Comment: the error tells you exactly what the problem is.. part of learning is understanding meaning.. if you have a method look at the number of params that it takes ..you can't pass more arguments to a method that expects less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it with four arguments:

```
ResellerBL.UpdateReseller(resellerId, name.Text, mobileNumber.Text, referenceNumber.Text);
```

But it only accepts one:

```
public static void UpdateReseller(Reseller reseller)
```

Two options are

1. Create a new reseller object and pass that:

.

```
var myreseller = New Reseller();
myresller.Id = resellerId;
//etc

ResellerBL.UpdateReseller(myreseller);
```

OR

2. Modify the (or add an overloaded) method to take the four arguments:

.

```
public static void UpdateReseller(int resellerId, string resellerName, string resellerMobile, string resellerRefNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UpdateReseller` method takes a single parameter: A `reseller`.

If you want to be able to pass individual parts to the method, you need to modify the signature or create an overload with the appropriate parameters.